# jquery simple menu roll-over (without animation queue)

Tags: jquery, animation, queue, hover

I have a simple unordered list with list items as menu item
i created the jquery just to have a funny rollover effect
being:

```
$('#nav ul ul li').hover(function(){
$(this).animate({ 
        marginLeft: "20px",
      }, 300 );
}, function(){
$(this).animate({ 
        marginLeft: "0px",
      }, 300 );
});
```

the problem with this script is, if you rush over the menu several times, an animation queue builds up.
i tried to use .stop()  in between, but then it also stops the animations from the other list items which should return to default state in any case.
is there a way to stop() the queue per item? but not for the whole list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why  $(this)**.stop()**.animate(...) is not working for you, but you can also try this approach:

```
$(":not(:animated)", this).animate(...)
```

which will only trigger the animation on elements that are not currently animated

Comment: where would you add the stop() then?
because what i have with stops, is that if you rush over the whole list, the 10th item for example uses stop then animates his way to 20 pixels to the right, but the stop prevented previous items 1 - 9 from returning to default state. 20pixels left.

Comment: uuhm, Sander I'm not sure I understand the exact issue you are having, could you please post your js/html online http://jsbin.com

Comment: hm, i just now realize my mistake
i added the .stop() @ the end, after the animate.
i used it like you do (before) and that seem to work ok.

thanks

yes the result can be seen @  www.komtuveu.be (left menu)
though this is just simple html ol list with text,
now i can style it and add the image. thanks